# Is a memory warning received on the main thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have seen some unusual behavior when my app responds to memory warnings - data getting out of sync primarily.

If my app receives a memory warning, will the warning pass control to the main thread?

If not, I assume I must do some data protection if the memory warning will free data that might be in use on the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` will only be called on the main thread.

Regardless, this is what you can do to ensure this without (potentially) deadlocking:

```
void invokeBlockOnMainThread(dispatch_block_t block) {
   if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
      block();
      return;
   }

   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

Call this function within `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`, passing in a block with everything that you need done and then you are guaranteed to be on the main thread while executing the code in the passed-in block.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the recommended use of the `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` method is to toss out views, and given that views should only be manipulated from the main thread, it is safe to assume that the method will only be ever invoked on the main thread.

If you ever find that this is not the case, or you would like this to be explicitly stated in the documentation, please [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com).